# ibatis domain modelling

Tags: model, dns, ibatis

I am working on the domain model for a project. I have a class named user that has a class named UserType as one of the properties. I know when I want to select all users, I will use joins to pick up all corresponding usertypes. How do I do inserts? Do I have to write a handler for userType? Or can I do something like

```
INSERT INTO users(... usertype_id ...) VALUES(... #{usertype.usertype_id}...)
```

Please help;

I have spent the whole day trying to figure this out. I am using ibatis 3.0 and I am new to ibatis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ibatis is not a full ORM framework, so it doesnt know about objects relationships.
So yes, you must write something like your *INSERT* if you want to work directly with domain objects that do not fully correspond to a record in your table; that is, if the User object you are mapping in Ibatis does not have a `getUsertypeId()` method (that returns the value corresponding to the table column usertype_id  ) but instead a `getUserType()` method.

(Of course you can also write a  `getUsertypeId()` method which internally calls `getUserType().getId()`... but just stop here and don't pretend to make also a `setUserTypeId(int id`) which internally tries to load the UsertypeId from the Db, etc, etc... that calls for trouble. You'll end reinventing JPA/Hibernate.)

I don't think a *TypeHandler* is the right approach, that feature is more oriented to converting non-trivial types, not so much for handling relationships.

Another valid approach is to have a layer of relatively low-level-dumb POJOs, roughly one for each table, with properties that map directly to your table columns (say, a `UserDb` object with a `userTypeId` property and no `getUserType()` method, and no bussiness intelligence, dependencies on upper layers or persistence knowledge), and then, on top of that, a layer of richer "real" domain objects, each of which wraps a (usually small) graph of those "dumb" POJOs, and has the intelligence necessary for calling the persistence layer (eg DAO) to load/save the graph (perhaps lazily).

One advantage of this approach is that the core of actual ibatis mappings (the SQL coding) can be done fairly automatically with [Ibator](http://ibatis.apache.org/ibator.html) - it even creates the code of the POJOs from the DB schema.

For massive reads of data which involves many tables (reports), you can create other trviial ad-hoc POJOs (which corresponds directly to the columns of your SELECT, and perhaps have some rudimentary intelligence to display values - something like a 'ViewModel') ... or even HashMaps.

PS: You might want to read about [DDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825751/ddd-view-objects) (and concepts like "Entities", "Value objects", "Views", "contexts" "rich domain object" vs "anemic domain objects" [eg](http://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-in-practice)). Ibatis gives you much flexibility to learn and implement along this lines.

Comment: some links for people passing thru: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design DDD and http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/Generator for ibator replacement.